# how to print array in subclass which is assigned in main class without any imports

Tags: java

for example

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            int[] arr = new int[args.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            {
             arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }
            printarr pp = new printarr();
            pp.pnt(arr);
    }
}

public class printarr{
    public int pnt(int[] arr){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(+arr[i]);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

i dont know but something is wrong please help me out
when ever i compile it it gives
printarr.java:6: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
return arr;
^
1 error

Comment: 1. Why have you tagged `python`? 2. What is unclear to you with the error message? It clearly says `int[]` cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: I highly recommend going through a tutorial or a book on java. You will learn very slowly if every time you have a slight hiccup, you resort to asking a question online.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the array `arr` in the `pnt()` method, but the return type of your `pnt()` method is int. Either return an integer or change the return type to int[]. Or change it to void and return nothing, you don't really need to.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an `int[]`, not an `int`. You could change the return type of `pnt` to `int[]`, but, to be honest, you don't really need it, and can just change the return type of `void` and omit the `return` statement altogether:

```
public void pnt(int[] arr){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(+arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to have a new class just to print an array.
Here an example with a `static void` method.

```java
public static void print(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(+arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I would go even with simpler way doing this:

```java
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: if i could i would if the main clas is pre fixed in a course which i am following and its non editable so i have only control of subclass

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is an int but you return an array of int
Try this

```
public int[] pnt(int[] arr){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(+arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```